# How to use react stateless component when API response didn't got yet?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working with react in Laravel, and i'm trying to built a simple FriendsList component to display data from API. 
The problem is that the Parent (Profile) component is finish loading before it's get the data, so the FriendsList component return an error, because the props are empty for the first time. It's important to say that regardless of the API response - the parent (Profile) component works well, it's loaded for the first time empty - and then the data is adding.

The Api call

```
 export const getProfile = () => {
 return axios
     .get('api/profile', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
     })
    .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
 }
```

The Parent Component

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import { getProfile } from './UserFunctions'
        import FriendsList from './FriendsList';

        class Profile extends Component {
            constructor() {
                super()
                this.state = {
                    name: '',
                    hobbies: '',
                    user_bday: '',
                    members: [],
                    error: '',

                }

            }

            componentDidMount() {

                getProfile().then(res => {
                    //   console.log(JSON.parse(res))
                    this.setState({
                        name: res.user.name,
                        hobbies: res.user.hobbies,
                        user_bday: res.user.user_birthday,
                        related_friends: res.user.related_friends,
                        members: res.user.members,

                    })

                })
            }


            render() {

                return (
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
                            <div className="col-sm-4 mx-auto">
                                <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
                            </div>
                            <table className="table col-md-4 mx-auto">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Name</td>
                                        <td>{this.state.name}</td>
                                        <td>{this.state.hobbies}</td>
                                        <td>{this.state.user_bday}</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <FriendsList members={this.state.members}> 
       </FriendsList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

        export default Profile

    import React from 'react';
     class FriendsList extends React.Component {

      render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        const { members } = this.props;
        const listmembers = members.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item + index}>{item.name}</li>
        ));
        return (
          <div>
            {listmembers}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default FriendsList
```

Comment: Why not set the initial `members` state to an empty array instead of a string?

Comment: Should you utilize state's `members` property in order to supply data to `friends` prop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

**First approach:**

```js
class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    // check if your `state` has all the necessary values
    // before rendering your JSX

    const { name, hobbies, user_bday, members } = this.state
    const shouldRender = name !== '' && 
      hobbies !== '' &&
      user_bday !== '' &&
      Array.isArray(members) && members.length > 0

    if (!shouldRender) {
      return null;
    }
    return (...)
  }
}
```

This way, you're only rendering `JSX` when your `state` has everything that you need.

---

**Second approach:**

```js
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    // ...
    this.setState = {
      members: []
    }
  }
}
```

Set your `members` to an empty array, rather than an empty string, so that way when you're passing it as `prop` to `FriendList` component, calling `this.props.friends.map` is actually correct, but it won't render anything since the array is initially empty.

---

Also, it looks like you are never updating your `members` after your API call finishes:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  getProfile().then(res => {
    this.setState({
      name: res.user.name,
      hobbies: res.user.hobbies,
      user_bday: res.user.user_birthday,
      related_friends: res.user.related_friends,
    })
  })
}
```

So your `members` actually stays as an empty string. Make sure your updating your state with the right type, which in this case should be an array.

Comment: Thanks - i did something else - but your comment helped me to understand the probelm better

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you're talking about `null props`... Also, Kellen in the comments is correct... You should set members to an empty array instead and I do not see you updating the state for members in your `setState`...

Try:

```
render() {
    const friendsList =
        this.props.firends &&
        this.props.friends.map(function(item, index) {
            <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>;
        });

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{friendsList}</ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question I guess you need to take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types, I think your problem is with the default props value and this library could help you achieve the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here would be to use `loading` state, during which you'll show a loading indicator, etc.

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      hobbies: "",
      user_bday: "",
      members: "",
      error: "",
      isMembers: false,
      loading: true // Add loading state
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getProfile().then(res => {
      //   console.log(JSON.parse(res))
      this.setState({
        name: res.user.name,
        hobbies: res.user.hobbies,
        user_bday: res.user.user_birthday,
        related_friends: res.user.related_friends,
        loading: false // Remove the loading state when data is fetched
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <p> Loading... </p>
    ) : (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
          <div className="col-sm-4 mx-auto">
            <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
          </div>
          <table className="table col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>{this.state.name}</td>
                <td>{this.state.hobbies}</td>
                <td>{this.state.user_bday}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          {/*<FriendsList friends={this.state.members}></FriendsList>*/}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -for some reason the props in the FriendsList  compoent aren't updating - i don't get any errors , but it's looks like while the Parent component is updates - the child's props aren't....

Comment: You need to update your question and show how you pass those props. I can see you iterate over `this.props.friends` in your child component however the parent one doesn't have such prop on the state.